# FluentValidation - pre-validation / conditional validation with no code duplication

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to create Validation which is able to have two groups and block second validation if first fail (it contains many rules).

For now I did create a private 'BasicValidation' class inside and in 'main validator' do sth like this:

```
RuleFor(m => m).SetValidator(new BasicValidation()).DependentRules(() => {
//Complex validation
RuleFor(m => m.IdOfSthInDb)
    .MustAsync(ItemMustExists)
    .WithMessage("Item does not exist.");
});
```

It does the trick but I would like to avoid creating that 'BasicValidation' for each model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my previous answer I misunderstood the question. The main goal is to avoid code duplication in different validators. After some investigation I found solution that matches your requirements. Suppose you have models:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public string BaseProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string BaseProperty2 { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel : BaseModel
{
    public int IdOfSthInDb { get; set; }
}
```

You have to create validator for base model (it would be used further):

```
class InternalBaseModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BaseModel>
{
    public InternalBaseModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.BaseProperty1).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Property 1 is empty");
        RuleFor(x => x.BaseProperty2).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Property 2 is empty");
    }
}
```

Then you can use new feature of FluentValidation, called [PreValidate](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#using-prevalidate):

```
public class BaseModelValidator<T>: AbstractValidator<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    // necessary for reusing base rules
    private readonly InternalBaseModelValidator preValidator; 

    protected BaseModelValidator()
    {
        preValidator = new InternalBaseModelValidator();
    }

    protected override bool PreValidate(ValidationContext<T> context, ValidationResult result)
    {
        var preValidationResult = preValidator.Validate(context.InstanceToValidate);
        if (preValidationResult.IsValid)
        {
            return true;
        }

        foreach(var error in preValidationResult.Errors)
        {
            result.Errors.Add(new ValidationFailure(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage, error.AttemptedValue));
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

After creating validator for all base models you can inherit from it for ChildModel validation:

```
public class ChildModelValidator : BaseModelValidator<ChildModel>
{
    public ChildModelValidator() 
        : base()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.IdOfSthInDb)
            .MustAsync(ItemMustExists)
            .WithMessage("Item does not exist.");
    }

    private Task<bool> ItemMustExists(int arg1, CancellationToken arg2)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(false); // some logic here
    }
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 3):

I think hext code would solve your problem:

```
var basicValidator = new BasicValidation();
RuleFor(m => m).SetValidator(basicValidator));

When(m => basicValidator.Validate(m).IsValid, () => 
{
    RuleFor(m => m.IdOfSthInDb)
        .MustAsync(ItemMustExists)
        .WithMessage("Item does not exist.");
});
```

Comment: Almost what I wanted :-) It give me some idea but I've to get 'similar task' to work on it a bit.  - still however 'BasicValidation' class for each model is needed.